# Scoping Filter: adminDescription NOTSTARTSWITH User_ Group_ etc

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

What does the scoping filter "adminDescription" actually look at for sync rules in Azure AD Connect.  Specifically for the User Join and Group Join rules there are scoping filters that look like the following.

For users:

```
adminDescription  -  NOTSTARTSWITH  -  User_
```

For groups:

```
adminDescription  -  NOTSTARTSWITH  -  Group_
```

As a background, I'm in the process of upgrading from Azure AD Sync to Azure AD Connect and found that these new scoping filters are auto-created.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is my understanding that the Scope Filter decides whether the particular rule actually applies to the object or not. So for one of the above examples:

adminDescription  -  NOTSTARTSWITH  -  User_

If the adminDescription attribute of the user object DOES NOT START WITH "User_", then the rule applies, else it is skipped and the processing moves on to the next rule.

Comment: Sorry it took me 4+ years to mark your answer as correct, I literally never came back to do that. You are in fact correct! This rule is very handy to block objects from syncing to AzureAD without explicitly excluding them in the scoping rules or filters.